# No logro ensanchar modal Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, modal

Tengo una ventana modal para asociar una propiedad a un formulario, pero el modal aparece muy angosto y parece estar debajo del navbar superior:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo html es:

```
<div id="modalPropiedades" class="modal" >

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
       
            <h4 class="modal-title">BUSQUEDA DE PROPIEDAD</h4>
        </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="table-responsive"> 
            <table id="propiedades" class="display" >
                     <thead>
                    
                    </thead>
                        <tbody>
                     
                        </tbody>
                                            
                    </table>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y el CSS:

```
        .modal{
      background-color:white;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position:relative;
      margin:0 auto;
      padding:3em;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  
    }
```

Ya he probado con modal-lg y sigue igual

Comment: Crea el modal desde cero en lugar de usar los de bootstrap. Creeme no tendrás problemas a la hora de modificar sus propiedades

Comment: Y como sería desde cero? No es mucho código tampoco

Comment: Y que haría esa función?